# Writing a sequence file from an image in local to HDFS using Java and Spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

As the title says, that is my objective now.

- I need to load a bunch of non-text files from a directory
- extract the usual file information from them (creation date, author, type... those ones)
- Create a sequence file of the type
- put the fresh extracted info in the Key of the .seq file
- store all of them in a hdfs directory.

The reason I'm using spark is for scalability (thousands of files to process and I will have a cluster of worker available) and because I'm thinking of implementing a SParkStreaming receiver on the image directory, so that the files will be processed automatically. 
Here is my initial code:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> imageRDD = jsc.wholeTextFiles("file:///home/cloudera/Pictures/");

    imageRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String,String>, Text, Text>() {

        @Override
        public Tuple2<Text, Text> call(Tuple2<String, String> arg0)
                throws Exception {
            return new Tuple2<Text, Text>(new Text(arg0._1),new Text(arg0._2));
        }

    }).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hdfs/sparkling/try.seq", Text.class, Text.class, SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
```

Here I load an image as a text file and create a tuple with the Text type from the hadoop library. This works, but:

1. The file isn't saved as a single one, but as a folder containing the partitions.
2. It isn't an array of byte, but a text representation of the file. We all know how nagging it can be to reconvert from text to image (or whatever it is)
3. If I load the files like this, Will there be a way to extract the required information?

I've tried to load the files as aa`sparkContext.binaryFiles(<directory>)`, but I'm always lost as how to extract info and on how to save them.
I can't seem to find the answer in the internet: does anybody of you know something about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did this:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, PortableDataStream> imageByteRDD = jsc.binaryFiles(SOURCE_PATH);
        if(!imageByteRDD.isEmpty())
            imageByteRDD.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<Tuple2<String,PortableDataStream>>>() {

            @Override
            public void call(
                    Iterator<Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream>> arg0)
                    throws Exception {
                Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                conf.set("fs.defaultFS", HDFS_PATH);
                while(arg0.hasNext()){
                    Tuple2<String,PortableDataStream>fileTuple = arg0.next();
                    Text key = new Text(fileTuple._1());
                    String fileName = key.toString().split(SEP_PATH)[key.toString().split(SEP_PATH).length-1].split(DOT_REGEX)[0];
                    String fileExtension = fileName.split(DOT_REGEX)[fileName.split(DOT_REGEX).length-1];

                      BytesWritable value = new BytesWritable( fileTuple._2().toArray());
                         SequenceFile.Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(
                                 conf, 
                                 SequenceFile.Writer.file(new Path(DEST_PATH + fileName + SEP_KEY + getCurrentTimeStamp()+DOT+fileExtension)),
                               SequenceFile.Writer.compression(SequenceFile.CompressionType.RECORD, new BZip2Codec()),
                               SequenceFile.Writer.keyClass(Text.class), SequenceFile.Writer.valueClass(BytesWritable.class));
                         key = new Text(key.toString().split(SEP_PATH)[key.toString().split(SEP_PATH).length-2] + SEP_KEY + fileName + SEP_KEY + fileExtension);
                            writer.append(key, value);
                         IOUtils.closeStream(writer);

                }
            }
        });
```